# Delay Chosen.js search filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using chosen.js for multiselect drop downs, but when I have a long list of options, the search filter is unbearably slow.

It appears the filter is being applied after each letter that is input, so I'm thinking it would be quicker if I could disable the filter until a minimum number of letters were input or after an amount of time passed since the last key input.

I'm initializing my chosen drop down like so:

```
$(".chzn-dynaselect").chosen({ width: '250px', search_contains: true });
```

And I'm attempting to delay the filter like so:

```js
var timer = 0;
$('.search-field input').on('input', function () {
    if (timer) 
    {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".chzn-dynaselect").chosen().trigger("chosen:activate")
    }, 400);
});
```

This code correctly triggers on input, but doesn't delay the filter. The filter still triggers after every keyup.

Is there a way to keep the search box, but turn off the filter event temporarily?

Answer (score 0):

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) 1st argument should be a function (or a string, see the docs for setTimeout)

```
timer = setTimeout(function () {
    $(".chzn-dynaselect").chosen().trigger("chosen:activate")
}, 400);
```

Comment: Thanks, Mauricio! Missed that. But even with that, it appears the Chosen search is still filtering after every letter is input. Is there any way to keep the search box, but delay the filter event until after a minimum amount of letters or until the user has stopped typing? Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Try _.debounce() instead of setTimeout()